# Link with text-overflow ellipsis in a list-item on next line in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have this very basic link ('a' element) with ellipsis overflow in a list-item:

```css
a {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This results in Google Chrome in:

```
*
  test
```

In Firefox this results in:

```
* test
```

I want the latter. But why do Google and Safari fail to render this correctly and how to fix this?

Comment: Just did a quick test. Unfortunately I think that if you omit the `display-block` the `text-overflow: ellipsis` no longer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by using `display:inline-block` on the `<a>` element:

```css
a {
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 100%; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Adding `float:left` gives a weird result in Safari. That does not seem a valid solution.

Comment: Great! Adding `display: inline-block` seems to solve this issue. Do we need to file this bug?

Comment: I have a deeper look into this later again to get the reason why this happens and update this answer. I got a similar problem a few days ago.